# Too high bandwidth in capturing multiple STILL images from multiple webcams with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, arduino

Now, I'm doing a project in which many webcams are used for capturing a still image for each webcam using OpenCV in C++.

*Like other questions*, multiple HD webcams may use too much bandwidth and exceed the limit.

*Unlike the others*, what I need is only **a still image (only one frame)** from each webcam. Let's say I have 15 webcams connecting to PC and every 10 seconds I would like to get still images (one image per webcam (total 15 images)) within 5 seconds. The images are then analysed and send a result to an arduino.

Approach 1: Open all webcams all the time and capture images every 10 seconds. 
Problem: The bandwidth of USB is not enough.

Approach 2: Open all webcams but only one webcam at a time, and then close it and open the next one.
Problem: Switching the webcams from one to another takes at least 5 seconds for each switching.

What I need is **only a single frame of an image from each webcam** and **not a video**.

Is there any suggestions for this problem, besides loadbalancing of USB bus and adding USB PCI cards?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In opencv you can deal with the WebCam as stream which mean you have run as video. However, I think this kind of problem should be solved using the Webcam API if it is available. There should a way or another to take still image and return it to your program as data. So, you may search for this in website of the Camera.